# .hover JQuery not working, but other JS functions are working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a .hover function that will change the size of a div from 50px to 150px, however every different script I've found online doesn't work in my current file.

I think this script works because I've used it before in different projects.

Here's my Code:

```js
//sidebar hover animation

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#Box1").hover(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#Box1').hasClass('unpressed')) {
      $('#Box1').css('width', '50px');
      $('#Box1').removeClass('unpressed');
    } else {
      $('#Box1').css('width', '150px');
      $('#Box1').addClass('unpressed');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#sidebarBoxes {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 108;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.sidebarBox {
  height: 51px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c1c1c2;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'texgyreadventorregular';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#Box1 {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebarBoxes">

  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box1">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box2">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box3">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box4">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box5">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box6">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box7">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box8">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box9">
    art
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've loaded the javascript on a .js file, which is running other scripts just fine, except this one. Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Use this code: `$(".sidebarBox").hover(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('unpressed')) {
        $(this).css('width', '50px').removeClass('unpressed');
    } else {
        $(this).css('width', '150px').addClass('unpressed');
    }
});`

Comment: Works on chrome as is.

Comment: I see that, dang. Weird, cuz I'm using Chrome as well and the results aren't at all the same. Tushar, I'm sure that code is right, but now that I see this I think the problem may lie elsewhere.. You guys have any idea where I should look?

Comment: @Tushar has the right answer.

Comment: but you want it for all, right?

Comment: check this fiddle, which is @Tushar's code: http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/8j2m4qfz/

Comment: well I want it to hover over each div individually and make them change individually.

Comment: you need this as jQuery? there's a pure CSS answer below.

Comment: so Tushar's code works on the jsfiddle, my code works in the "run snippet" on here, and so does the answer below. However, It doesn't work when i plug it in to the actual files. It doesn't list any errors either.

Comment: well, you've got other issues then. run your HTML through a validator perhaps.

Comment: figured it out. In the rest of the code I have an invisible div over everything, which apparently prevents you from hovering over lower elements. Live and learn! Thanks guys, and thanks Tushar for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript to do this. You can use CSS `:hover` selector and describe any rules which should be applied to the elements on hover:

```css
#sidebarBoxes {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 108;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.sidebarBox {
  height: 51px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c1c1c2;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'texgyreadventorregular';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sidebarBox:hover {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebarBoxes">

  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box1">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box2">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box3">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box4">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box5">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box6">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box7">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box8">
    art
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarBox" id="Box9">
    art
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```